# How are the size of the stack and heap limited by the OS?

Tags: linux, memory, stack, heap

**Note**: if you need to consider a specific OS to be able to answer, please consider Linux.

Whenever I run a program, it will be given a virtual memory space to run in, with an area for its stack and one for its heap.

**Question 1**: do the stack and the heap have a static size limit (e.g., 2 gigabytes each), or is this limit dynamic, changing according to the memory allocations during the execution of the program (i.e., 4 gigabytes total to be used by both, so if a program only uses the stack, it will be able to have a stack with 4 gigabytes)?

**Question 2**: How is the limit defined? Is it the total available RAM memory?

**Question 3**: What about the text (code) and data sections, how are they limited?

Comment: Stack: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux/239323#239323

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two different memory limits. The virtual memory limit and the physical memory limit.

### Virtual Memory

The virtual memory is limited by size and layout of address space available. Usually at the very beginning is the executable code and static data and past that grows the heap, while at the end is area reserved by kernel, before it the shared libraries and stack (which on most platforms grows down). That gives heap and stack free space to grow, the other areas being known at process startup and fixed.

The free virtual memory is not initially marked as usable, but is marked such during allocation. While heap can grow to all available memory, most systems don't auto-grow stacks. IIRC default limit for stack is 8MiB on Linux and 1MiB on Windows and can be changed on both systems. The virtual memory also contains any memory-mapped files and hardware.

One reason why stack can't be auto-grown (arbitrarily) is that multi-threaded programs need separate stack for each thread, so they would eventually get in each other's way.

On 32-bit platforms the total amount of virtual memory is 4GiB, both Linux and Windows normally reserving last 1GiB for kernel, giving you at most 3GiB of address space. There is a special version of Linux that does not reserve anything giving you full 4GiB. It is useful for the rare case of large databases where the last 1GiB saves the day, but for regular use it is slightly slower due to the additional page table reloads.

On 64-bit platforms the virtual memory is 64EiB and you don't have to think about it.

### Physical Memory

Physical memory is usually only allocated by the operating system when the process needs to access it. How much physical memory a process is using is very fuzzy number, because some memory is shared between processes (the code, shared libraries and any other mapped files), data from files are loaded into memory on demand and discarded when there is memory shortage and "anonymous" memory (the one not backed by files) may be swapped.

On Linux what happens when you run out of physical memory depends on the `vm.overcommit_memory` system setting. The default is to overcommit. When you ask the system to allocate memory, it gives some to you, but only allocates the virtual memory. When you actually access the memory, it will try to get some physical memory to use, discarding data that can be reread or swapping things out as necessary. If it finds it can't free up anything, it will simply remove the process from existence (there is no way to react, because that reaction could require more memory and that would lead to endless loop).

This is how processes die on Android (which is also Linux). The logic was improved with logic *which* process to remove from existence based on what the process is doing and how old it is. Than android processes simply stop doing anything, but sit in the background and the "out of memory killer" will kill them when it needs memory for new ones.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's easier to answer this by the order of how the memory is used.

**Question 3: What about the text (code) and data sections, how are they limited?**
Text and Data are prepared by the compiler. The requirement for the compiler is to make sure that they are accessible and pack them in the lower portion of address space. The accessible address space will be limited by the hardware, e.g. if the instruction pointer register is 32-bit, then text address space would be 4 GiB.

**Question 2: How is the limit defined? Is it the total available RAM memory?**
After text and data, the area above that is the heap. With virtual memory, the heap can practically grow *up* close to the max address space.

**Question 1: do the stack and the heap have a static size limit (e.g., 2 gigabytes each), or is this limit dynamic, changing according to the memory allocations during the execution of the program (i.e., 4 gigabytes total to be used by both, so if a program only uses the stack, it will be able to have a stack with 4 gigabytes)?**
The final segment in the process address space is the stack. The stack takes the end segment of the address space and it starts from the end and grows *down*.

Because the heap grows up and the stack grows down, they basically limit each other. Also, because both type of segments are writeable, it wasn't always a violation for one of them to cross the boundary, so you could have buffer or stack overflow. Now there are mechanism to stop them from happening.

There is a set limit for heap (stack) for each process to start with. This limit can be changed at runtime (using brk()/sbrk()). Basically what happens is when the process needs more heap space and it has run out of allocated space, the standard library will issue the call to the OS. The OS will allocate a page, which usually will be manage by user library for the program to use. I.e. if the program wants 1 KiB, the OS will give additional 4 KiB and the library will give 1 KiB to the program and have 3 KiB left for use when the program ask for more next time.

Most of the time the layout will be Text, Data, Heap (grows up), unallocated space and finally Stack (grows down). They all share the same address space.